# how to overcome division by zero in the Hodgkin Huxley neuron model

Tags: computational-biology, neural-network, neuroscience

I've implemented the Hodgkin Huxley model, which worked fine in my visualization, I got the spiking etc.
Then I've build a network with a few thousand neurons and experienced random NAN (not a number) flooding the network; I could track it down to how sodium and potassium are updated. e.g.

VoltageDelta = MembranVoltage - ReferenceVoltage

AlphaNa = 0.01 * (VoltageDelta - 10.0) / (1.0 - exp( -(VoltageDelta-10.0) / 10.0))

If the voltage delta is exactly 10, the exp(0) returns 1, which ends up being a division by zero. I've compared my implementations to other, and despite some reordering of computations, all seem to have this flaw. I haven't found anything about how to deal with that.
I could add a check and assume it's 0/0 -> 0, yet I'm not sure whether close to 0 values would lead to numerical inaccuracies and I wonder how this is usually handled. ( I've looked into some github implementations, and haven't seen special handling).

Edit:
some implementations you can find:
https://github.com/swharden/HHSharp/blob/master/src/HHSharp/HHModel.cs
https://github.com/openworm/hodgkin_huxley_tutorial/blob/master/Tutorial/Source/HodgkinHuxley.py

The original paper:
[https://www.sfn.org/~/media/SfN/Documents/ClassicPapers/ActionPotentials/hodgkin5.ashx](https://www.sfn.org/%7E/media/SfN/Documents/ClassicPapers/ActionPotentials/hodgkin5.ashx)

Comment: Can you include the links to the github implementations and the other implementations that you found?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
AlphaNa = 0.1 * f(0.1*(VoltageDelta-10.0))
```

where
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{1-\exp(-x)}
$$
The limit for $x\to 0$ can actually be interpreted as difference quotient, you might also appeal to l'Hopital, to find that $f(x)\to 1$. So if you want to play it safe, you can employ a 3-tier or 4-tier implementation of this function

```python
def f(x):
    if abs(x)<1e-12: return 1
    if abs(x)<1e-4: return -x/expm1(-x)
    if x<-20: ex = exp(x); return -x*ex/(1-ex)
    return x/(1-exp(-x))
```

The formula as it originally is can still produce non-representable intermediate values if $-x$ is moderately large so that $\exp(-x)$ produces a floating-point overflow. This should compensate automatically in the division, but to be sure I added the case `x < -20`.

Comment: To expand on this answer, consider the Taylor series expansion of this function at $x=0$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+x%2F%281+-+exp%28-x%29%29%2C+x%3D0